# Looking for a drawing module with jpg output possibility

Tags: python, image, module, drawing

I am searching for a (simple) drawing module so I could draw a couple of squares, append the text on them and output that to the `.jpg` file. I was trying to use the `PIL` module, however I failed due to the `PIL` not working properly with `Windows` (requires lots of additional libraries like `libjpeg`).

So the question is - is there any fairly simple python module for drawing and saving the output to the image-type file?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had trouble with PIL on windows, but you could try [SimpleCV](https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv).  It even has simple in the name.

```
from SimpleCV import Image
img = Image('lenna.jpeg')
img.drawRectangle(x=10,y=10,w=50,h=50,color=(255,0,0))
img = img.applyLayers()
img.save('lenna_rect.jpeg')
```